# How to deploy angular(for frontend) and spring boot (for backend) on the same server (wildfly)

Tags: java, angular, spring, spring-boot, wildfly

I have created APIs in Spring Boot and deployed my war file on the Wildfly server and the endpoints are working, but now I have to deploy the front-end part which is Angular, and I am not getting any solution regarding this.

How to deploy the spring boot war file and angular content on the Wildfly server?